# Android Display Cursor Result In Two Different Listview In One Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, whatsapp

Any idea on how to display cursor result in two different listview in the same activity? An example is from Whatsapp where they have (I presume) a "Chats" table and "Messages" table. Once we type the keyword on the toolbar I will query both tables and display in two different listviews in 1 activity. Is there any way to do this? Or are they displaying in 1 single listview only? Please advice.

Thank you.

[image: Whatsapp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done. To mimic the above in a simple way, assume a database has two tables chats and messages. They both have two columns a unique identifier and a column for the text.

Using a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper we could have a file named **DBHlpr.java** as:-

```
public class DBHlpr extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    static final String CHATTABLE = "chats";
    static final String MSGTABLE = "messages";

    static final String TEXTCOL = "textdata";
    static final String IDCOL = "_id";


    DBHlpr(Context context) {
        super(context,DBNAME,null,1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CHATTABLE + " (" + IDCOL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + TEXTCOL + " TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + MSGTABLE + " (" + IDCOL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + TEXTCOL + " TEXT)");
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
    }

    public void insertRow(String table, String text) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TEXTCOL,text);
         long id = this.getWritableDatabase().insert(table,null,cv);
        Log.d("DBHLP-INSRT","Added row with ID=" + Long.toString(id));
    }

    public Cursor getRows(String table, String srchstr) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        String whereclause = null;
        if (srchstr.length() > 0) {
            whereclause = TEXTCOL + " LIKE '%" + srchstr + "%' ";
        }
         return db.query(
                table,
                null,whereclause,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

The `onCreate` method will create the 2 tables namely **chats** and **messages** (as per CHATTABLE and MSGTABLE).

`onUpgrade is required but does nothing as yet.`

`insertRow` can be used to add a row to either table (as they both have the same structure). Note that it will write to the log so the insert can easily be confirmed.

`getRows` is used to get a Cursor (data from the database) containing the data. Again this one method can be used for both tables. It is passed a string which is used (if it's length is greater than 0) to filter the tables (as per data entered in the search field).

The activity will require a layout that specifies two ListViews, in this case it will be **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mjt.so45787986.MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chats" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Messages" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

There is nothing special, it's a very simple layout, with an EditText for the search criteria a TextView as a heading for the chat list (the following ListView) and then another TextView and ListView for the messages.

**MainActivity.java** could be :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHlpr dbhlpr = new DBHlpr(this);
    Cursor chatcursor;
    Cursor msgcursor;
    TextWatcher tx;
    EditText search;
    ListView chatlist;
    ListView msglist;
    SimpleCursorAdapter chat_sca;
    SimpleCursorAdapter msg_sca;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        chatlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chats);
        msglist =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages);


        // Add some data for testing

        dbhlpr.insertRow(DBHlpr.CHATTABLE, "This is my first chat");
        dbhlpr.insertRow(DBHlpr.CHATTABLE, "This is my second chat");
        dbhlpr.insertRow(DBHlpr.CHATTABLE, "This is my third chat");
        dbhlpr.insertRow(DBHlpr.MSGTABLE, "First Message");
        dbhlpr.insertRow(DBHlpr.MSGTABLE, "Second Message");
        dbhlpr.insertRow(DBHlpr.MSGTABLE, "Third Message");

        chatcursor = dbhlpr.getRows(DBHlpr.CHATTABLE,"");
        chat_sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                chatcursor,
                new String[]{DBHlpr.TEXTCOL},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
                );
        chatlist.setAdapter(chat_sca);
        msgcursor = dbhlpr.getRows(DBHlpr.MSGTABLE,"");
        msg_sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                msgcursor,
                new String[]{DBHlpr.TEXTCOL},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );
        msglist.setAdapter(msg_sca);

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                refreshCursors();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshCursors() {
        chatcursor = dbhlpr.getRows(DBHlpr.CHATTABLE,search.getText().toString());
        chat_sca.swapCursor(chatcursor);
        msgcursor = dbhlpr.getRows(DBHlpr.MSGTABLE,search.getText().toString());
        msg_sca.swapCursor(msgcursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        chatcursor.close();
        msgcursor.close();
    }
}
```

First some class variables are defined:-

```
    DBHlpr dbhlpr = new DBHlpr(this);
    Cursor chatcursor;
    Cursor msgcursor;
```

Are Database related. The first creates an instance of the DBHlpr, the other two are for the 2 Cursors (chats and messages).

```
TextWatcher tx;
EditText search;
ListView chatlist;
ListView msglist;
```

Are for handling the views. TextWatcher is used for detecting changes to the search.

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter chat_sca;
    SimpleCursorAdapter msg_sca;
```

Are for adapting the Database data to the ListViews. These, as the name implies, are pretty basic but will do for demonstration purposes.

The first 5 lines in the `onCreate` are pretty standard.

The next 6 lines are all basically the same i.e. `dbhlpr.insertRow(DBHlpr.CHATTABLE, "This is my first chat");` and invoke the insertRow method passing the respective table and the data to be stored. It should be noted that the very first time the first is run is when the database will be created. Note these lines exists only to provide some testing data.

Then we come to (note the code following this is basically repeated but for the message table):-

```
    chatcursor = dbhlpr.getRows(DBHlpr.CHATTABLE,"");
    chat_sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            chatcursor,
            new String[]{DBHlpr.TEXTCOL},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0
            );
    chatlist.setAdapter(chat_sca);
```

The first line gets a Cursor with the respective data (all chat rows, as per the 2nd parameter).
The 2nd-9th lines is a single command that sets up the Simple Cursors Adapater (1st parm is the context, 2nd the layout to use (we cheat and use a simple one), 3rd is the Cursor that holds the data, 4th is the column from where the data in the cursor is to be obtained, 5th is the views id where the data will be placed, 6th should be 0).
The last line tells the ListView to use the adapter.

Following this the TextWatcher is added to the search. In this the onTextChanged method is used, which calls the `refreshCursors` method.

The `refreshCursors` method gets the data from the database, using the changed search data, into the existing cursors and then tells the adpater, via `swapCursor` that the data has changed.

Last the `onDestroy` method is used to close the cursors when the Activity is about to end.

When initially run :-

[image]

After typing **f** in the search field :-

[image]